# problem example ROS C++ no rule to make target libboost_signals

Tags: ros, c++, catkin-make, publisher, libboost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 server.
I installed ROS hydro base, and follow the examples, but when I'm trying to make the Publiser/Suscriber example (C++)
I have the following error

make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libbost_signals-mt.so', needed by '/home/rosvm/catkin_ws/devel/beginner_tutorials/listener'. Stop.

make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listener.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134796/problem-example-ros-c++-no-rule-to-make-target-libboost_signals/) by [crhistian](https://answers.ros.org/users/12671/crhistian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is and there will be no Debian packages of Hydro for Ubuntu 13.10. You may either:

- build Hydro from source (http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source)
- or use a supported platform for which Debian packages of Hydro are available (http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#hydro-medusa-aug-2013)

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK ROS Hydro is not yet fully supported on 13.10. Have you installed using the repository or from source?

You can try creating a symbolic link for the needed file

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_signals.so /usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.so`

or if that does not work you could try installing the libboost-singals package used in 13.04

`sudo apt-get install libboost-signals1.49-dev`

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-03-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2014-07-31**:
I ran into the same issue compiling against ros indigo on trusty. soft link trick works well. I think this deserves a ticket on the ros issue tracker.